# XSLT Creating Nested Elements under existing context while respecting namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

Consider the following input xml:

```
<b:PropertyInfo id="N91" xmlns:b="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
    <b:CommlPropertyInfo id="N92" LocationRef="LOCATION1">
        <b:SubjectInsuranceCd id="SubjectInsuranceCd-1">BLDG</b:SubjectInsuranceCd>
        <b:CommlCoverage id="N95">
            <b:CoverageCd id="N96">BLDG</b:CoverageCd>
            <b:Limit id="N97">
                <b:FormatInteger id="N98">250000</b:FormatInteger>
                <b:ValuationCd id="N99">RC</b:ValuationCd>
            </b:Limit>
        </b:CommlCoverage>
        <b:CommlCoverage id="N100">
            <b:CoverageCd id="N101">INFL</b:CoverageCd>
            <b:Limit id="N102">
                <b:FormatPct id="N103">100</b:FormatPct>
            </b:Limit>
        </b:CommlCoverage>
    </b:CommlPropertyInfo>
</b:PropertyInfo
```

Where the desired output is:

```
<b:PropertyInfo id="N91" xmlns:b="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
    <b:CommlPropertyInfo id="N92" LocationRef="LOCATION1">
        <b:SubjectInsuranceCd id="SubjectInsuranceCd-1">BLDG</b:SubjectInsuranceCd>
        <b:CommlCoverage id="N95">
            <b:CoverageCd id="N96">BLDG</b:CoverageCd>
            <b:Limit id="N97">
                <b:FormatInteger id="N98">250000</b:FormatInteger>
                <b:ValuationCd id="N99">RC</b:ValuationCd>
            </b:Limit>
            <CommlCoverageSupplement xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
                <CoverageSubCd>INFL</CoverageSubCd>
                <AnnualIncrease>100</AnnualIncrease>
            </CommlCoverageSupplement>
        </b:CommlCoverage>
        <b:CommlCoverage id="N100">
            <b:CoverageCd id="N101">INFL</b:CoverageCd>
            <b:Limit id="N102">
                <b:FormatPct id="N103">100</b:FormatPct>
            </b:Limit>
        </b:CommlCoverage>
    </b:CommlPropertyInfo>
</b:PropertyInfo>
```

I have an xslt that does almost exactly what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/" >
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="PropertyInfo/CommlPropertyInfo/CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='BLDG']">
        <xsl:variable name="increase">
            <xsl:value-of select="../CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='INFL']/Limit/FormatPct" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <CommlCoverageSupplement>
                <CoverageSubCd>INFL</CoverageSubCd>
                <AnnualIncrease>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$increase" />
                </AnnualIncrease>
            </CommlCoverageSupplement>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My concern with this transform is it uses raw text elements to create new elements - which won't have the correct namespaces and hence the xml produced by it is incorrect. From my reading, my understanding is it's "bad practice" to use raw text to create xml elements. My understanding is utilizing raw text in this manner should be utilized when you are transforming xml into another format, such as html.

So I tried to use the `<xsl:element>` to resolve this, however I'm using it incorrectly. As I have it written, the xslt processor is letting me know it's invalid format to have an `<xsl:element>` nested within another:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- "other" template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="PropertyInfo/CommlPropertyInfo/CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='BLDG']">
        <xsl:variable name="increase">
            <xsl:value-of select="../CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='INFL']/Limit/FormatPct" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:element name="CommlCoverageSupplement" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                <xsl:element name="CoverageSubCd" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">INFL</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="AnnualIncrease" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$increase" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is the proper XSLT way to create new nested elements like this while still respecting namespaces?

EDIT: It turns out this was only an editor bug. You can actually create nested xsl:element elements and the answer is actually in the question re-posted here for clarity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <!-- element template that copies over elements -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- "other" template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="comment() | processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="PropertyInfo/CommlPropertyInfo/CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='BLDG']">
        <xsl:variable name="increase">
            <xsl:value-of select="../CommlCoverage[CoverageCd='INFL']/Limit/FormatPct" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
            <xsl:element name="CommlCoverageSupplement" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                <xsl:element name="CoverageSubCd" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">INFL</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="AnnualIncrease" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$increase" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*I have an xslt that does almost exactly what I want*"  What is the **exact** result that you vant to get?

Comment: Updated to include a sample xml of the desired output. I should note that any namespace semantic equivalent (with prefixes or whatever) is also acceptable. Anything where the structure i provided is created while belonging to the default-namespace the xslt specifies.

Comment: The output you show is not well-formed XML, because the `b:` prefix is not bound to a namespace. Your input has the same flaw.

Comment: I don't understand 'my understanding is it's "bad practice" to use raw text to create xml elements'. Are you thinking that using literal result elements in the form of `<CommlCoverageSupplement>...</CommlCoverageSupplement>` is bad practice? I don't agree at all with that thinking. As for "the xslt processor is letting me know it's invalid format to have an <xsl:element> nested within another", can you show a minimal but complete stylesheet using nested `xsl:element` where you get an error?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I added the b namespace declaration in the sample xmls. I forgot to add them after minimizing the xml for this example (my real xml size is measured in mb and not conducive for SO questions).

Comment: @Martin Honnen, I was pretty sure I read it in Michael Kay's book "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0" yesterday. If i find the quote again I will provide it. I'm now confused because I could have swore the xslt I wrote utilizing xsl:element nodes wasn't working yesterday and reporting that nested xsl:element elements is not allowed. Now upon creating a full sample for you it is (posted as the second xslt in my question) - it's working. Perhaps I need more coffee in the morning before making SO posts :( I will try to rediscover what the real issue was yesterday from my "large" xslt.

Comment: I was able to replicate the issue late last night by chance. It turns out it was an editor bug that was complaining about nothing (close the xslt editor and re-open and it goes away). The answer to this question is actually in my question, I will edit that to make it more clear. If I can find the quotation from XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 I will provide it. In the interim I think it may be worthwhile to consider utilizing the xsl:element instead. It is namespace aware and will help you prevent your code from having to care about prefixes (assuming your xml deals with one namespace)

Comment: @Russ The  `xsl:element` is required when the name and/or the namespace of the element needs to be calculated at runtime.  Otherwise using a literal result element - either with a prefix, or with a default namespace declaration - is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I beileve that if you add the following namespace declaration:

```
xmlns:b="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/"
```

to the `xsl:stylesheet` element, and add the `b:` prefix to the literal result elements:

```
    <b:CommlCoverageSupplement>
        <b:CoverageSubCd>INFL</b:CoverageSubCd>
        <b:AnnualIncrease>
            <xsl:value-of select="$increase" />
        </b:AnnualIncrease>
    </b:CommlCoverageSupplement>
```

you will get the output that you *need*.

---

If - for some strange reason - you don't want the added elements to have the `b:` prefix (but still be in the same namespace), you could do simply:

```
     <CommlCoverageSupplement xmlns="http://www.ACORD.org/standards/PC_Surety/ACORD1/xml/"> 
        <CoverageSubCd>INFL</CoverageSubCd>
        <AnnualIncrease>
            <xsl:value-of select="$increase" />
        </AnnualIncrease>
    </CommlCoverageSupplement>
```